# Identifying what date this value represents in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am brand new (!) to SQLite and will not be studying or using it long-term; however, I am trying to paw through a bit of archived data in a sqlite database using db browser for sqlite.

There is a table with a date field with a value like this:  1435610912000000

Does that make any sense to anyone as to a date of some kind ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the number of microseconds from 1970 (epoch). Therefore, that is 1435610912000 milliseconds (or 1435610912 seconds), which converts to Mon Jun 29 2015 20:48:32 UTC using [this](http://currentmillis.com/) website.

Comment: the date from the website you sent after conversion is not Mon Jun 29 2015 20:48:32 UTC

Comment: Using this website also confirms the Jun 29 date: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm when plugging in 1435610912 seconds.

Comment: what poster sent is 1435610912000000

Comment: Yes, which is the time in microseconds since 1970, which I have converted into seconds here for ease of use. Why this has been stored as microseconds is another problem to be looked into. However, the answer must be in microseconds, because seconds and milliseconds lead to a date that is far to big and unexpected for a dated SQL entry.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a timestamp which every programming language has a function for converting it to a Date objec.

```
var date = new Date(1435610912000000);
```

This code above is Javascript that casts the number 1435610912000000 to date

```
Sat Sep 13 47462 01:53:20 GMT+0100 (WAT)
```

which is a bit off but the best guess is that it is a timestamp